# How to reload parent view in Vaadin without table reseting sort order

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using PagedFilterTable in Vaadin to manage pagination. When loading default page, I have set something like this - and I include sorting by some field:

```
if(this.sortField != null){
    table.setSortContainerPropertyId(this.sortField);
    table.setColumnWidth(this.sortField, 80);
    table.setSortAscending(true);
    table.sort();
}
```

So that happens when the page is loaded and that is fine. After I submit new entry (**entries are being added through new, popup window**), table gets new row, but the table loses it's sort order in view after popup closes, so sorting is no longer keeped. Problem is I do not know how to get to that table element from that popup window and set sorting again. Why table is being updated and I see it, and sort doesen't? Problem is bigger because I have both windows in separate files and seems to me I can't grab table element easily without modifiying the logic because I am in another window.

How to reload table so that the sort stays same?

I managed to do this after submit:

```
getUI().getPage().reload();
```

With that it works, but I am not satisfied. After that line of code, everything reloads again (meaning all queries execute again). Result is good but I don't want after submit whole reloading of page happens (also because none of my other buttons do reload). So I would like only to reload table in parent window.

**How can I grab table object from outside window and for example set it's change to immediate and correct change?**

Something like this I suppose needs to be written:

```
getParent().getUI().setImmediate(true);
```

?

**Or better question, how to manage to table sort remains the same after inserting new entry through new window?**

Comment: Page reload is doing too much. Usually you only add the new item to the container and then the table is automatically informed about the new data and displays this

Comment: Really don't know how to do this..

Comment: How do you populate your table? (Usually the Container handles this)

Comment: I populate it inside myTable = new AbstractPagedTable(dataSource); Where myTable is defined as: private AbstractPagedTable myTable;

That is called with: myLayout.addComponent(generateMyTable(tableData));

and myLayout is defined as: myLayout = new VerticalLayout();

Comment: the interesting "beast" is the tableData. Can you please add your code as a edit to the question?

Comment: tableData = new BeanItemContainer<CreditExt>(CreditExt.class, creditService.getAll());

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. On the parent window in the windowCloseListener I just added:

```
myTable.refreshTable(data);
myTable.sortTable(); // my custom method that was Invoked on the page load too
```